# standard Cauchy distribution in multi-variate case

Tags: probability-theory

> Cauchy distribution on $\mathbb R^d$. Let $Z$ take values in $\mathbb R^d$. It is said to have the standard Cauchy distribution if
> $$\mathbb P\{Z \in dx\} = dx \frac{d+1}2 ( \frac{1}{\pi(1+|x|^2)})^{(d+1)/2}, \quad x\in\mathbb R^d.$$
> Then, $\mathbb E e^{ir \cdot Z} = e^{-|r|}, r \in \mathbb R^d$. Show that $Z$ has the same distribution as $X/Y$, where $X = (X_1, ..., X_d)$ is a $d$-dimensional standard Gaussian, and $Y$ is a one-dimensional Gaussian independent of $X$. Note that each component $Z_i$ has the standard one-dimensional Cauchy distribution, but the components are dependent. Show that, for every vector $v \in \mathbb R^d$, the inner product $v \cdot Z$ has the one-dimensional Cauchy distribution with scale factor $|v|$, that is
> $$\mathbb P\{v \cdot Z \in dx\} = dx \frac{|v|}{\pi(|v|^2 + |x|^2)},\quad x \in \mathbb R.$$

I know that the ratio of standard normals in one-dimension is standard Cauchy, but I am confused about the multi-dimensional case. I think the component of $X$ is not independent given that the author says "the components of $Z$ are dependent".

$\mathbb E e^{ir\cdot X/Y} = \mathbb E e^{i (r_1 X_1 + ... + r_d X_d)/Y}$. Let $K = r_1 X_1 + ... + r_d X_d$. Then, $K \sim N(0, \sigma_K^2)$ for $\sigma_K^2 = \text{Var}(r_1 X_1 + ... + r_dX_d)$. That means, $\mathbb Ee^{i r\cdot X/Y } = \mathbb E e^{i\sigma_K (K/\sigma_K)/Y} = e^{-|\sigma_K|}$. The last equality comes from the facts that $K/\sigma_K$ and $Y$ are independent, and both are $N(0,1)$ (though, I am not sure if the author meant $Y$ to be $N(0,1)$). Now, how do we know $|r| = |\sigma_K|$?

Answer (score 1):

You are actually almost there already.
You just have to calculate the variance of $r_1 X_1 + \dots + r_d X_d$ using standard properties of the variance and independent random variables. If you like, I can write it down, but I think you will manage.

To your question regarding dependence: Note that we have $Z_i \sim X_i/Y$. Then the $Z_i$ need not be independent even if the $X_i$ are, because they all depend on the same $Y$.